# Java ZipInputStream throws zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back while parsing nested zip files

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

I'll start of with acknowledgment that I've read several threads here and on the internet and my problem persists and seems to be something different.

I have a zip file which contains several .txt files, directories, subdirectories to this directories and so on. There also plenty zip archives inside with zips, directories and files inside. Deepest level of archivization is 5 steps -> 5 zips, one inside of another with different files along with them.

I have this code:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(Objects.requireNonNull(this.classLoader.getResource("inputs.zip")).getFile());
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
        processZipFile(stream);
    }
```

and here's processZipFile:

```
private void processZipFile(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(stream);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    while (zipEntry != null) {
        System.out.print("    /" + zipEntry.getName());
        if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
            processZipFile(stream);
        }
        zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
```

Until level 3 of archivization everything seems to be working fine, all the directories, zips, gzips and sub directories are listed but then when it comes to handle something like inputs.zip/1.zip/2.zip it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
```

As I have read in Java 8 docs `ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()`:
`Reads the next ZIP file entry and positions the stream at the beginning of the entry data.` Because just after getting entry programs throws exception.

In this certain case, file inside of "2.zip" is rather big - 800 MB comparing it to other cases with max size of 3 MB - I wonder if it might affect program.

I'm trying to do all of these things without unpacking these zips, it's really important here. I'm aware this kind of error is commonly related to corrupted zip files, but these ones are totally legitimate.

So my question is - how I can go through all of these nested zip files?

EDIT/SOLUTION:

According to change proposed by Talex I've fixed my code to work on `ZipInputStreams` rather than standard `InputStreams`. It was not throwing errors anymore but somehow it was still skipping nested zips deeper than 3 levels of archivization (still not sure if it's proper naming approach lol). Solution to this was also simple - I wrapped `ZipInputStream` to another `ZipInputStream` when passing it recurrently to my function. Here's code:

```
private void processZipFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry zipEntry;
    while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println("    " + zipEntry.getName());
        if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
            processZipFile(new ZipInputStream(zipInputStream));
        } else if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
           //other things to todo...
        }
        //other things to todo...
    }
```

Comment: There is no [tag:gzip] or [tag:nio] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Sorry, indeed my bad, it's related to the problem not question strictly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
processZipFile(stream);
```

you need to use

```
processZipFile(zipInputStream);
```

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have thought about that, it works indeed, upvoted your answer @talex but I will mark it as best if You can provide some information why it works this way or at least some reading sources so me and others in future might get more from it

Comment: `zipInputStream` have your data unzipped, while `stream`  contains raw data.